# USB HDD not found

Tags: debian, external-hdd

Some time ago I bought an external HDD 2TB. Now I am encountering a problem: My computer doesn't see it when I plug it in. (I tried Gparted, and some other program that I found on the internet). Because I want to format it, I tried these commands, but it is not shown:

```
lsusb

sudo fdisk -l
```

Shows only in:

```
dmesg | tail -n 20
```

messeage:

```
[ 1639.785187] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1639.785190] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 1639.977010] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1639.977017] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 1640.057076] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1640.057083] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1640.525073] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1640.525077] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 1640.780937] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1640.780940] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 1641.188905] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2138.683015] usb 4-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 2138.872871] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a
[ 2138.872879] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, 
SerialNumber=3
[ 2138.872883] usb 4-1.1: Product: Expansion
[ 2138.872887] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 2138.872890] usb 4-1.1: SerialNumber: NAA7A6D6
[ 2138.876706] scsi host6: uas
[ 2138.878489] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0710 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2138.911706] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

OS- Debian Stretch (also used win 7)

Comment: Please edit question with the *complete* part of `dmesg` where it shows up. If it doesn't show in `lsusb`, that suggests a hardware problem. How do you power the external HDD? How much power does the USB port provide? Can you power it via a powered USB hub, or an external power connection to the HDD?

Comment: @dirkt It is powered properly. week ago it worked normally. Power. I plug it right into USB port and it starts up and it works normally.

Comment: Are you *sure* it doesn't show up in `lsusb` after you plug it in? Please edit question with output of `lsusb`. Normally `dmesg` would contain error messages if the USB connection has an error. Also note that this device uses [UAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI), you may need a newer kernel than in Debian Stretch (but I didn't check what Stretch uses) to make it work properly.

Comment: I googled and it looks like UAS started working around kernel version 3.15. What's your kernel version?

Comment: @dirkt 4.9.0-8-amd64

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try disabling uas in your kernel for this device vendor. I had a similar problem with my external USB enclosure and this resolved the problem. Below are my full notes which I refer to everytime I have to address this issue (e.g. after a fresh Ubuntu install). This was still necessary for me as recently as 18.04.3 LTS with kernel 5.0.0-36-generic.

Here's the solution (for my LaCie drive, external Seagate enclosure, etc) hanging system on
boot and not showing up in fdisk.
The 059f:105e is the vendor/product string for the LaCie drive, so if
you do this for another drive, use the appropriate string as printed for this
device by 'lsusb' ('lsusb -t' may also be useful).
What this does is disable UAS for this vendor/product string only, and then
rebuilds the latest kernel with this fix. I did this and then the system
booted quickly and showed the drive in fdisk right away!

Caution: if you have a separate file for each quirk in modprobe.d it
won't work! Whichever file is read last probably overwrites the previous one.
So, you MUST enter the quirks on a single line separated by commas.

Here's how to fix the problem:

```
sudo su
cat > /etc/modprobe.d/disable-uas.conf
```

A single device would look like this:

```
options usb-storage quirks=059f:105e:u
```

Multiple devices is done like this. Here both LaCie and Seagate enclosure are modified.

```
options usb-storage quirks=059f:105f:u,059f:105e:u,174c:1351:u
```

(ctrl-D to exit)

```
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

If you want to get things working without rebooting, this also works:

```
rmmod uas usb-storage
modprobe usb-storage quirks=174c:1351:u,059f:105e:u,059f:105f:u
```

## Appendix

Here are some useful commands for debugging USB device status:

- fdisk -l
- usb-devices
- lspci -nv
- lsusb
- lsusb -t

NOTE: there was another approach I previously used that involved editing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
and adding the following lines which worked for the LaCie drive at one point:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="059f", ATTR{idProduct}=="105e", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", 
MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", 
ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1", TAG+="uaccess"
ATTR{idVendor}=="059f", ATTR{idProduct}=="105f", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", 
MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", 
ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1", TAG+="uaccess"
```

But this seems unnecessary now and the modprobe approach works fine on its own. And it also
seems like this approach stopped working at some point, maybe because I updated to a newer
Ubuntu or kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is three years old but I've got a possible solution that wasn't mentioned.
An external drive of mine was fine until one day it started having issues, and then it was no longer recognized. When I used `fdisk -l` it didn't show up, but the light was on, and the disk did not spin at any time.

The solution turned out to be dead simple. I opened it up and saw the actual drive was loose from the USB interface. I connected it properly and it was suddenly recognized on the computer, mounted it and it was in 100% working condition. Nothing more to it than that!